# updating partial but not entire page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sitefinity

I am using the code below on my page and the partial renders as can be seen below. I have added the partial for reference. I have got a next button on the partial, when I click the button it goes to the server and returns the next page from the server as a partial. I would like to know how can I updates the partial data but not the entire page.

Main.cshtm

```
<div class="pr-nav">
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        User Guide
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary">
        Key Info
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

@{ Html.RenderPartial("Partial"); }
</div>
```

Partial.cshtml

```
  <div>
        <ul class="dashbord">
            @foreach (var i in Model)
            {
                <li class="item"><a href="@Url.Action("", "CISIProfessionalRefresherController", new { subjectID = i.subject_id })">
                    <div class="itemBox">
                        <div class="itemImage">
                            Image will go here
                        </div>
                        <div class="itemContent">
                            @i.subject_title
                            <br />
                            @i.cpd_time_text
                            <br />
                            @i.sub_heading
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a></li>

            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    @if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "getMySubjectList", new { catogoryId = 0, pageid = Model.PageNumber - 1 })
    }

    else
    {

        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;");

    }
    &nbsp;
    @if (Model.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "getMySubjectList", new { catogoryId = 0, pageid = Model.PageNumber + 1 })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.Raw("&nbsp;")
    }
```

Comment: this tutorial was quite helpful when I was trying to learn how to do this properly:  http://chsakell.com/2013/05/10/ajax-and-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: You need to use ajax to update the current page

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 1):

Say if your Prev and Next have id "#aPrev" and "#aNext", then you can:

```
$(".container").on("click", "#aPrev,#aNext", function(){
        $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
              $(".container").html(data);
       })
})
```

extra note,

for setting Prev and Next Id, you can use:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "getMySubjectList", new { catogoryId = 0, pageid = Model.PageNumber - 1, id = "aPrev" })


@Html.ActionLink("Next >", "getMySubjectList", new { catogoryId = 0, pageid = Model.PageNumber + 1, id = "aNext" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that by default Sitefinity will return the full page html when you request one of your Action methods via Ajax.

You need to register a custom MVC route first and then send an ajax request to that action. In your action method check if Request.IsAjaxRequest() and then return the partial view.

Register MVC route Example (v.8):

```
Bootstrapper.MVC.MapRoute(name: "ajaxRoute",
                                    url: "ajax/{controller}/{action}/{departmentUrl}/{page}",
                                    defaults: new
                                    {
                                        controller = "ProductList",
                                        action = "Index",
                                        departmentUrl = UrlParameter.Optional,
                                        page = UrlParameter.Optional
                                    });
```

Sample request to the custom route:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.Products,
                    p => Url.RouteUrl("ajaxRoute",
                        new
                        {
                            controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
                            action = "Index",..
}
```